# How to compile classpath resources on maven package?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, pom.xml

I included a project as dependency in another project. On maven `package` the included dependency is not compiled as jar, but an empty folder is created.

projects:

```
main-test (packaging: jar)
main-webservice (packaging: war)
```

the main-webservice project includes the jar with pom.

main-test pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

main-webservice pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.main</groupId>
    <artifactId>ws</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.main</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build><plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
</plugins></build>
</project>
```

The dependencies of the test project are resolved inside webservice project, so the pom seems to be correct.

Anyhow, if I run "mvn package", the resources of `main-webservices` compile to target, but the `libs` folder contains another *folder* named `main-test-1.0.jar`. BUT it's a folder, not a packed jar.

What could be wrong here? How can I get the project to be packaged as jar, not as folder?

Comment: I've never seen that happen before. You will probably need to post more of your poms, the problem is obviously not in the tiny snippet your provided.

Comment: see my update above. What I noticed: when I go the the maven libraries view in eclipse of my main-webservice project, the dependency `main-test` is also not included as a jar, but as a folder.

Comment: In Eclipse its normal, its "workspace resolution" that is doing that. Basically its Eclipse's way of telling you its a dependency managed by another project in the workspace.

Comment: "included dependency is not compiled as jar" -> Maven never compiles dependencies. It just takes them as they are and either puts them on the classpath or copies them into the WAR. But it never *changes* the artifact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> included dependency is not compiled as jar

Maven never compiles dependencies. It just takes them as they are and either puts them on the classpath or copies them into the WAR. But it never changes the artifact.

That also means the dependency must be in your local repo (somewhere below `~/.m2/repository/`) or Maven will be unhappy (= fail with an error).

Note: Maven doesn't have a big memory. It can always only keep a single module in his tiny brain. In Eclipse, you can add another project as it is to the build path but Maven can't do that. For Maven to work properly, you must install all the dependencies in your local repo.

Comment: Hm ok. So, when I run 'mvn package' on my webservice project, is there any chance to tell maven to automatically `install` the referenced open workspace projects into repo?

Answer (score 0):

Idea:

- Check if the jar exists in your repository
- Check if the jar project in eclipse is not referenced in the war project in the Java Build Path
- Do it without eclipse mvn plugin:

  mvn eclipse:clean (for both projects)

  mvn eclipse:eclipse (for both projects)

  mvn clean install (for both projects)

Comment: Hm the file does not exist in the maven `.m2` repository, as I want to prevent having to directly `install` the jar to depo. I just want it to be found and build by maven as I have both projects open in my workspace.